# Java generics and collections: Why it is possible to assign float list to List<? super Integer>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

In Java generics topic stated, that expression `? super Integer` means any type(class) that has Integer as super class(Including Integer.class).
Then why following behavior possible?

```
List<? super Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? super Float> floatList = List.of(1.1f,2.2f);

intList = floatList;   
//Not possible, Required type: List <? super Integer> Provided: List <capture of ? super Float>

intList = List.of(1.1f,2.2f);
//Ok, intList will now contains float values
```

I do understand that in runtime there is no generics, but why there is no compilation error?

Comment: `List.of(1.1f, 2.2f)` could be considered a `List<Number>` and `Number` is a superclass of `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

`List<? super Integer>` means that the actual type is `Integer` or one of its super types: `Number` or `Object`, but also `Comparable` or `Serializable`.

When you assign `List.of(1.1f,2.2f)` to `intList`, the compiler tries to find a match. It finds one that's not `List<Integer>`; I'm guessing `List<Number>`. The result is a list that you can add `Integer` instances to. That it may also contain non-`Integer` values is not an issue here.

This is also the reason why you cannot extract elements as `Integer` but only `Object` (or the wildcard, `?`).

Comment: The compiler does not try to infer the type of the list from its arguments. That would indeed end up at `List<Float>`and fail, as was the case before Java 8. Since Java 8, the target type (left hand side of the assignment operator) determines the type of the expression which is not `List<Number>` but `List<? super Integer>`. Then, the subexpressions are checked against the derived constraints but for `? super …`, any argument will fulfill the constraints. You can also write `intList = List.of();` where the right side has no arguments to derive a stand-alone type.

Answer (score 2):

> In Java generics topic stated, that expression `? super Integer` means any type(class) that has Integer as super class(Including Integer.class).

No, that's backwards.  The type expression `? super Integer` means an unspecified type that is a superclass *of* `Integer`, or is `Integer` itself.  Supposing that we are talking about `java.lang.Integer`, and referring to the Java 21 standard library, that means one of  `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Number`, `java.lang.Object`, `java.lang.Serializable`, `java.lang.Comparable<Integer>`, `java.lang.constant.Constable`, or `java.lang.constant.ConstantDesc`.

A `List<? super Integer>` is one to which you are certain to be able to *add* an `Integer`, but which provides no guarantees at all about what other types of objects might also be within.

> [...] why following behavior possible?

> ```
> List<? super Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
> // [...]
> intList = List.of(1.1f,2.2f);
> ```

Because Java can infer the type of the list to be any number of compatible things that would accomodate objects of type `Float`, such as `List<Number>` or `List<Object>`.  It doesn't actually need to choose one in this case -- it is sufficient to know that there are viable options.  The compiler cannot safely assume that the list referred to as a `List<? super Float>` has one of those types, however, which is why your other assignment is rejected.

If you want a `List` that can contain any object of class `Integer` or any subclass of `Integer` then that is spelled `List<Integer>`.

If you want to accommodate lists with any type parameter that is `Integer` or a subtype of `Integer` then that is spelled `List<? extends Integer>`.

Note that the latter allows you to assume that any object pulled from the list is an `Integer`, but not, formally, that you can add elements whose class is exactly `Integer`.  That's because if `Integer` were not `final` then you could have a subclass, say `SmallInteger`, that was the actual type parameter of the list.  Any object of that class is also an `Integer`, but an object whose class is `Integer` *is not* a `SmallInteger`.